# Как отцентрировать спрайт?

Tags: css

Есть кнопка навигации, в ней с помощью css задан круг:

```
.content_two_circle{
position: relative;
width: 68px;
height: 68px;
-moz-border-radius: 34px;
-webkit-border-radius: 34px;
border-radius: 34px;
background: #c5c5c5;
}
```

Внутри него в html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="content_two_circle" href="//"><span class="apple"> </span></a></li>
</ul>
```

задано изображение с помощью спрайта:

```
.apple{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
background: url(../images/sprites.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 0 -50px;
width: 27px;
height: 33px;
}
```

Отображается он вот так:
[image: результат]

Что нужно исправить, чтобы он отображался корректно:
[image: вот так]

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
.apple {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../images/sprites.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -50px;
    width: 27px;
    height: 33px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -13px;
    margin-right: -16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поправить примерно так:

```
.apple{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
background: url(../images/sprites.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 25px -25px;
width: 27px;
height: 33px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1 вариант**

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content_two_circle {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #c5c5c5;
}
.content_two_circle .apple{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    background: url(../images/sprites.png) no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-position: 0 -50px;
    width: 27px;
    height: 33px;
    margin: -16.5px 0 0 -13.5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="content_two_circle" href="#">
    <span class="apple"></span>
</a>
```

**2 вариант**

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content_two_circle {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #c5c5c5;
}
.content_two_circle .apple{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;
    background: url(../images/sprites.png) no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-position: 0 -50px;
    width: 27px;
    height: 33px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<a class="content_two_circle" href="#">
    <span class="apple"></span>
</a>
```